# Should we ask User details/preference before or after Sign up in a Mobile App?

Tags: forms, mobile

What is the best practice when it comes to asking user details (height,weight,Age,Country).

Should it be before signing up or Immediately after signing up ?
(To avoid low conversion rate, user height,weight,age is put in 1 screen and Name and email is on another screen)

Comment: There isn't a clear-cut answer to this. Generally you don't want to put impediments in the way of your users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answer:** After the sign up (You always want the user to first get on board with the application, Rest come later!)

**Long Answer:**

1. Simplest thing to do is observe how already established and successful applications do it.
   For example, Pinterest, Twitter asks user to select "area of interest" after signing up with the application.
2. If user is on-board with the application then there would be always time when you can prompt the user to add user details/preferences.
3. Be it on same screen or on different screen all users hate filling forms. User might leave the registration process half way if he/she gets frustrated. The become even more true on mobile when keypads are small.
4. It is also important to give ability to user to "Skip" adding these User details if it is not that critical. User can always complete the profile/preferences later.

So it is important that user is not bothered by form fields in registration process.
However being said the above, There are no hard and fast rules. If the user details are critical, then you can ask them along with the sign up form.
But my suggestion would be to avoid it whenever possible.

Answer (score 4):

Generally you want to reduce any initial friction, especially in B2C apps. So you ask for as little as possible at the start and make sure the user gets to experience the core value as quickly as possible.

Said that, there's one important consideration. Sometimes you need a bit of extra information at the start to deliver great value and experience. For example, you might ask a user for a topic of interest to hit him/her with highly relevant content. Without that, the user might not be sufficiently rewarded at the start and consequently might not invest more of his/her effort.

If you think that this is your case consider two options. First, think what minimum information would suffice and what's the easiest way to get it. Perhaps a single topic of interest will be enough to start with. Or perhaps instead of asking about food preferences you could use user's current position (which is easier to get) to tailor search results. Second, you might want to split your process into two steps. The goal of the first step is solely to minimize the friction, so you ask for email and password. After that the user is on board and has invested a bit, which is very important, he/she will be a bit more willing to answer one extra question. Now the goal of the second step is to get this extra bit of information. Make it fun and easy is possible, try to avoid forms. For example, show clickable topic cards, pics of food, etc. whatever your case is. But above all give a short, clear explanation or a hint as to why you're asking for this and what benefit the user can expect in return.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to ask for the info you require from your users to access and start using the app. The user shouldn't be blocked by an unnecessary question at any point during use of the app. Remember mobile, with slow connections and small screens and consider the impact of complex forms in this context.

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

1. Ask for minimal information on sign-up. This is usually an email address and a password, giving the user private access and ensuring no-one can sign up with an email address they don't own. Note, this shouldn't include verification of the email address immediately. Then, ask for required information as and when it becomes required. For example, you might want to know their country before you can tailor provided information for them more finely. Another example is email verification - that extra level of security might be required for many functions, but is it really required for the user to have a look around and decide whether the app is what they're looking for?
2. Ask for the info, but give a skip option. Facebook does this well (although they overload their home page sign up form, there's no need for them to ask about gender, for example). Once you've got in you're given the option to select a profile pic or give further info about yourself. This info isn't actually required to use the app, so you can skip and you never have to actually provide it.

This means the user achieves their goal (using your app) with minimal friction and if they choose a goal within your app that requires further info you target that friction to the use cases where it is actually relevant.

This process is known as [soft sign up](https://aaronparecki.com/2011/04/12/1/soft-signup-lower-the-barrier-to-entry).